# React-media query not working with large screen on pageload when hosting on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, gatsby, netlify

I'm using react-media v1.8.0 (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) with Gatsby and it's is working perfectly locally, but not working the same way when hosted on Netlify. I have set of photos that should be stacking on smaller screens and should be a grid on larger screens. As seen on this Netlify preview-branch under the red title that says "Non-contest Submission" (https://5bb630aec965921b43c49c7b--art-show.netlify.com/), if you load the site with a screen-width >768px, it doesn't load properly, but if you resize the screen <768px and then back to >768px, it loads properly. I'm not sure why there's an issue on initial load for larger screens.

Here's how I'm using react-media. In my render():

```
staffImages = (
  (photos).map((photo, i) => {

    let photoMobileURL = photo.url.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + 'lg'), "$1sm");

    return (
      <Media query={{ maxWidth: 768 }}>
        {matches =>
          matches ? (
            <GridPhotoContainer>
              <Photo
                className="Photo"
                backgroundImage={photoMobileURL}
                openModal={() => this.openModal(i, false, true)}
              />
            </GridPhotoContainer>
          ) : (
              <Photo
                className="Photo"
                backgroundImage={photo.url}
                openModal={() => this.openModal(i, false, true)}
              />
            )
        }
      </Media>
    )
  })
)

renderStaffImages = (
  <Media query="(max-width: 768px)">
    {matches =>
      matches ? (
        <Grid className="Grid">
          {staffImages}
        </Grid>
      ) : (
          <Grid className="Grid" marginTop="3em">
            {staffImages}
          </Grid>
        )
    }
  </Media>
)
```

then I'm returning {renderStaffImages} in my component's return statement.

Answer (score 0):

At the least, there should be a unique `key` assignment on your [list of components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) that are created when you build collections of elements using `map()`. Also, for performance, you should just make the decision what collection type to return based on a parameter rather than checking the media query in your loop which could have bad side effects.

### Try something like

```
staffImages = (small) => {
  const photoURL = small ? photo.url.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + 'lg'), "$1sm") : `${photo.url}`;
  return (photos).map((photo, i) => small ? (
    <GridPhotoContainer key={i}>
      <Photo
        className="Photo"
        backgroundImage={photoURL}
        openModal={() => this.openModal(i, false, true)}
      />
    </GridPhotoContainer>
  ) : (
    <Photo
      key={i}
      className="Photo"
      backgroundImage={photoURL}
      openModal={() => this.openModal(i, false, true)}
    />
    )
  )
} 

renderStaffImages = (
  <Media query="(max-width: 768px)">
    {matches => (
        <Grid className="Grid" marginTop={matches ? '0' : '3em'}>
          {staffImages(matches)}
        </Grid>
      )
    }
  </Media>
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, @talves. Your solution is really clean, although photo was not defined, so I just had to move it inside of the map function. I made this change, and just as before, it works perfectly locally and when I use `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve`, but still does not work on Netlify (https://5bbbaa65b31274423e434d5c--art-show.netlify.com/)

Comment: Yeah, without the code to debug, it is going to be hard to figure out what is causing this issue. I think you have a race condition on the query object, but that is just a guess at this point.